# Expressions anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq, expression, anonymous-types

Looking for a way to access an anonymous object's properties and values in an expression tree.  Ultimately, the key/value pairs passed via the anonymous object will be used as strings. I found how to access the key part, but I'm having trouble finding the value part.

Usage is:

```
object.ExpressionBuilder<Company>(dc => new { DCCODE = dc.CompanyCode })
```

Method is:

```
ExpressionBuilder<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expr) 
{
   var propertyName = expr.Body.Type.GetProperties()[0].Name; //this gets "DCCODE" as a string

   var valueName = "dc.CompanyCode"; //looking for a way to get the matching value as either "CompanyCode" or "dc.CompanyCode"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Note*: I cannot assure this will always be correct as the ordering *could* vary, a look at the source code should be done to determine this. However, this was fun to play with.

```
var body = (NewExpression)expr.Body;
var zipped = body.Members.Zip(body.Arguments, (member, argument) => new KeyValuePair<MemberInfo, MemberExpression>(member, argument));

foreach (var zip in zipped)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Property name: {0}, property argument: {1}", zip.Key.Name, zip.Value.ToString());
}
```

This will print:

> Property name: DCODE, property argument: dc.CompanyCode

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to parsing expressions is to create a custom `ExpressionVisitor`. An anonymous type construction is represented by `NewExpression` node from which you can access members as well as arguments.

```
public class CustomExpressionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitNew(NewExpression node)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{node.Members?.First().Name} {node.Arguments.FirstOrDefault()}");

        return base.VisitNew(node);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
var expressionVisitor = new CustomExpressionVisitor();
expressionVisitor.Visit(expr);
```

Which prints the first property with value:

> DCCODE dc.CompanyCode

Of course you can do whatever transformation you like on such an expression tree with this class.